# inconsistency in logging module python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to log various messages using the logging module in python.
I am unable to get the expected result. I am new to python.
The real issue is:

```
import logging as log

log.basicConfig(filename="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\log test\\test.log",level=log.INFO, format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

1. upon executing this, I do not get the date time in my log file.
2. `log.info("Hey, this is an info")` doesn't log anything in the file.

I need to restart the kernel every time to get the output.

Comment: This means the logging system has already been configured.  See the dupe for the `force` keyword to reconfigure it.

Comment: @wim neither that post answers my questions now, nor I can ask a new anymore. I am deleting my account itself. Why this community is brutal? I am new to python. I am learning.

Comment: Why doesn't that answer the question? Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Do I need to restart my kernel every time? And how to deal with such inconsistencies in the prod environment?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart the kernel if you use the `force` keyword when (re)configuring logging. **Note that force only works for Python-3.8+**.

Comment: thanks, it was helpful. You are god to me. It is working fine now.